# Working with PHP Sessions

Tags: php

I just developed a user login system and want to create different sessions for different users.

How do I write a code in PHP so that it starts a session and if the username entered is "a", it redirects to a different page and if the username is "b", it redirects to a different page.

#### Update:

I used this

```
session_start();

switch ($_SESSION['username']) {
    case 'a':
        // $_SESSION['username'] is 'a'
        // redirect to file1.php
        header('Location: file1.php');
        die();
        break;
    case 'b':
        // $_SESSION['username'] is 'b'
        // redirect to file2.php
        header('Location: file2.php');
        die();
        break;
    default:
        // $_SESSION['username'] is neither a, nor b, or is not set at all
        // redirect to default.php
        header('Location: default.php');
        die();
        break;
}
```

but no matter what username I enter, it is taking me to file1.php

Comment: is it just for some users that you want to redirect them to a different page, because if it's to send them to their profile-page (for example) you better use a $_GET parameter (in the url)

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start();

// ...

if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'a') {
    header("Location: ./page_a");
} else if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'b') {
    header("Location: ./page_b");
} else {
    header("Location: ./otherpage");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply start php sessions with:

```
session_start() ;
```

Then, on login, save the logged in user's id to:

```
$_SESSION['currentuser'] = $userid ;
```

On logout, don't forget to:

```
unset($_SESSION['currentuser']) ;
```

On the page you want to display differently to each user, check `$_SESSION['currentuser']` and then redirect:

```
if($_SESSION['currentuser'] == 1) {
    Header("Location:/page1.php") ;
} else {
    Header("Location:/page_default.php") ;
}
exit ;
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your PHP pages should start with:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

You'll set session variables like this:

```
$_SESSION['myVariableName'] = 'myIntendedValue';
```

So when you process the login, you'll likely set a session variable for username or userid, and then you can handle that redirection:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userName']) && $_SESSION['userName'] == "a") {
    header("Location: pageA.php");
    exit();
} else if (isset($_SESSION['userName']) && $_SESSION['userName'] == "b") {
    header("Location: pageB.php");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `switch()` instead of if statements:

```
session_start();

switch ($_SESSION['username'])
{
    case 'a':
        // $_SESSION['username'] is 'a'
        // redirect to file1.php
        header('Location: file1.php');
        die();
        break;
    case 'b':
        // $_SESSION['username'] is 'b'
        // redirect to file2.php
        header('Location: file2.php');
        die();
        break;
    default:
        // $_SESSION['username'] is neither a, nor b, or is not set at all
        // redirect to default.php
        header('Location: default.php');
        die();
        break;
}
```

Note that this alone isn't enough to be secure. In file1.php and file2.php you must also call `session_start()` and carry out a similar check that the user is allowed to view this page, before displaying the page content.

Comment: the switch is nice, but only if he needs more than 2 different pages in my opinion
else you're just writing more code

Comment: Hey, I used this but no matter what username I enter, it is taking me to file1.php . Can you please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: @Sarthak - how are you setting the username? Could do with seeing a code snippet!

Comment: I am using session_start();

switch ($_SESSION['username'])
{
    case 'sarthak':
        // $_SESSION['username'] is 'a'
        // redirect to file1.php
        header('Location: file1.php');
        die();
        break;
    case 'great':
        // $_SESSION['username'] is 'b'
        // redirect to file2.php
        header('Location: file2.php');
        die();
        break;
    default:
        // $_SESSION['username'] is neither a, nor b, or is not set at all
        // redirect to default.php
        header('Location: default.php');
        die();
        break;
}

Comment: where sarthak and great are the usernames.

Comment: Yes but where are you setting `$_SESSION['username']`?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I want to get the usernames from my PhpMyadmin database.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username'] == 'a')
   header('Location: pageA.php');
else
   header('Location: pageB.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the PHP.net documention on [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Basically, every page will start with `session_start()` to initiate the PHP session.  After that, you have access to the global `$_SESSION[]` array which you can use to store and read data.

For example, you could store the username in the session during the login process:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'a';
```

Then, in your other pages, you would read the session username, find out the username and do proper handling:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: newlocation.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like quantumSoup's code but He has made a simple error, use this:

session_start();

// ...

if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'a') {
    header("Location: ./page_a");
} else if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'b') {
    header("Location: ./page_b");
} else {
    header("Location: ./otherpage");
}

Comment: it's easier to read when you use the 'code'-button to mark your code

Comment: I can't seem to use that, I press it and it doesn't colour it.